# Connection String not working, cannot read file location

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, connection-string

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename="c:\users\skofiar\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Diploma_Project\Diploma_Project\STD_IBU.mdf";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT Student_ID, Name, Course_ID, Course_Name, Study_Program FROM Students CROSS JOIN StudentCourse", con);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);

    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

This part of the code shows error :

> c:\users\skofiar\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Diploma_Project\Diploma_Project\STD_IBU.mdf";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");

After that this error appears

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 28.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the double quotes around the folder name is causing the issue.  You open them at data source, them close them at the folder name.  I would try first removing the double quotes around the file name, I dont think they are required inside the connection string.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=c:\users\skofiar\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Diploma_Project\Diploma_Project\STD_IBU.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
```